# Cheap way of modeling friend relationships

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an app engine project (java) which has a User class. I'd like to model a cheap friend relationship system. Each user can have max 50 friends. I am thinking of doing something zany like:

```
class User {
    String username;
    Text friends; // "joe,mary,frank,pete"
}
```

Where "friends" is a comma delimited list of usernames that the user is friends with. Here are the operations I want to support and how I'd do them with the above:

---

**Fetch my full friend list**

Just look up the User object, return back the comma delimited list of friends.

---

**Add a friend**

Fetch my user object, check if the target name exists in the string, if not, append to the end. Persist modified User object back to data store.

---

**Delete a friend**

Fetch my user object, check if the target name exists in the string, if it does, delete it from the string. Persist modified User object back to data store.

---

**Are two users mutual friends**

Fetch both user objects, check that the usernames appear on one another's user object.

---

Getting a full list of friends is pretty important for my application, and storing each relationship as a separate entity seems nightmarish to me (fetching each entity from the datastore when a user needs to see their friends list would probably bankrupt me). I am hoping that a simple read from the Text attribute would be much more lightweight.

Checking for the mutual friend scenario seems like the biggest drawback here, but won't happen that often. I don't know if fetching the two User objects from the datastore and doing the string comparisons would be disastrous performance-wise. Might be ok? I think I may have also read that creating and deleting objects from the data store costs more than just modifying an existing object. So the add/delete friend operations might be better this way too.

Would be happy to hear any thoughts on this or more optimal ways of going about it.

Thank you

-------------------------- Update ---------------------

As per Adrian's comment, I could also do the following:

```
class User {
    String username;
    List<String> friends;
      // or //
    Set<String> friends; 
}
```

So I think if I use a List, those entities will get indexed by default. I'm not sure if I could execute a GQL query knowing that the lists are indexed to get a match without actually fetching any entities. Something like:

```
SELECT COUNT FROM User WHERE 
    (username = "me" && friends = "bob") &&
    (username = "bob" && friends = "me")
```

Storing as a Set would help do the search faster if I loaded both User objects, but I think for both the List and Set, extra time has to be taken to deserialize them when fetched from the datastore, so not sure if their benefits are negated. Maybe it would hurt more than it'd help?

Comment: could use an actual List<String> for the friends; or even better a HashMap<String> so you could get average O(1) look up and improve your friend list intersection operation. Given that you have max 50 friends, I doubt you'll run into performance issues no matter which design you choose.

Comment: Good point, I updated my question with that option. I think there is some penalty for serialization to the List or Set objects when reading / persisting to the datastore. I'm not sure if I could use a query to completely avoid that if using a List. That would be cool. Thank you

Comment: if you must go with the long string approach, you can speed up finding common friends by using a prefix tree. The problem becomes find substring of string A in string B.

Answer (score 1):

`List<String> friends;` is a good solution and one that I've seen in professional use. If friends have User IDs of your app or google you can use that data type for a list of keys instead.

Comment: Using lists on a similar case is explained on the "Building Scalable, Complex Apps on App Engine" presentation from Google I/O 2009 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgaL6NGpkB8

Answer (score 1):

I would actually suggest you store the data in two forms. First, a list of the usernames, and secondly, a matching list of datastore keys for those users' own entities.

This will allow you to both quickly display a user's friends, and look up one particular friend to check for a mutual relationship. In particular, it will almost certainly be more efficient to check the friend's list of friend keys for the original user's keys than to match on a string.

The only drawback will be keeping the two lists in sync, but given your list of operations that doesn't sound too hard.